# Outlook 2013 - edit subject of received meetings

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I use Outlook 2013, and as part of my job i receive meetings (they are forwarded to me as part of the workflow). I perform the work instructed in the meeting description, and then archive them. For my own notes, I edit the subject line of the meeting. This was easy and done exaxtly like you did in Outlook 2010 - open the meeting and type in the subject line and save. However, this is apparently not possible in Outlook 2013. I can't type in the subject line, and the actions button is hidden. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: By "actions" I mean the button that appears on the ribbon. I have not accepted the meeting invitation beboere attempting to editor; it worked fine in Outlook 2010.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Actions button", but I can open a Meeting sent to me, edit the subject and save it again no problem.  Have you accepted the meeting before trying to edit it?

Comment: user452915: In the future, please login to edit your question.  If you can't login, go to the [contact page](http://superuser.com/contact) and ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me. I've tested with a meeting invite that I haven't accepted.

All I do is make the changes I want and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>

Sometimes the ribbon commands get hidden if the display width isn't big enough but that doesn't impact the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a macro to accomplish this, as I am not holding my breath for M$ to restore this functionality that they inexplicably took away.

As before this functionality was broken, the "meeting item" of interest must be open to change the subject.

This macro may or may not break something, possibly including synchs with the Exchange server (but if the Exchange server can't deal with it, that is something else for M$ to un-break).

All disclaimers apply. Use at your own risk. YMMV, etc.

```
Option Explicit
Sub change_subject_of_currently_open_meeting_request()
        Dim oMail As MailItem
        Dim oMtg As MeetingItem

        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        Set oMtg = ActiveInspector.currentItem
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "This macro works only in an open MEETINGItem." & vbCrLf & "Will now exit macro."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        Dim strS, t, v, p, prompt, title
        strS = oMtg.Subject

        p = "Microsoft broke the ability to edit subject lines"
        p = p & vbCrLf & "of meeting requests in the 2013 version."
        p = p & vbCrLf
        p = p & vbCrLf & "This macro provides a way to do so."

        prompt = p
        title = "Provides the ability to edit meeting request subject lines, broken in Outlook 2013."
        t = InputBox(prompt, title, strS) ' prompt, title, default
        If t <> "" Then
           If t <> strS Then
              oMtg.Subject = t
           End If
        End If
End Sub
```